# Bash: Missing ']'

Tags: bash

I am getting the error: 
./Lab17Part3: line 4: [: missing `]'
when I try to run this code. Oddly enough, it then continues to work as intended.

```
#!/bin/sh
    #Delete a file interactively
    filename=$1
    if [ !-f $filename && !-d $filename ]
    then
      echo "There is no file \"$filename\"."
    else
      echo "Do you want to delete \"$filename\"?"
      read choice
      if test $choice = y
      then
        if [ -d $filename ]
        then
          rmdir $filename
          echo \"$filename\" deleted
        else
          rm $filename
          echo \"$filename\" deleted
        fi
      else
        echo \"$filename\" not deleted.
      fi
    fi
```

Why am I getting the error, as my line for definitely has a ']' to terminate it. I don't think there are any other syntax things missing. I remembered to have a space before the ']'.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find that!

Comment: btw, http://shellcheck.net/ will catch this kind of thing for you automatically. I'd strongly suggest running it against the above script as a whole.

Comment: Spaces are very important inside the `[` and `]` brackets of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line 4 should be:

```
if [ ! -f "$filename" ] && [ ! -d "$filename" ]
```

`[` is command in bash, better to say, it's alias for `test` command. It could be also written like

```
if test ! -f "$filename" && test ! -d "$filename"
```

Also please use double-quotes for enclosing variables. In case when $filename is `''` (empty string), my first condition would be expanded this way

```
if [ ! -f  ] && [ ! -d  ]
```

and it would cause syntax error. When you use double quotes, it's ok:

```
if [ ! -f "" ] && [ ! -d "" ]
```

Comment: Also, thank you for the syntax advice!

Comment: Not quite an error; `[ ! -f ]` becomes `[ ! -n "-f" ]`; so it's valid syntax, it just doesn't have the meaning it's supposed to have.